# Conditional expectation and LOTUS to prove an identity for $\mathbb E[B(X)\mid X>k]$.

Tags: probability-distributions, conditional-expectation

Let $X$ be a continuous and real random variable, with density $f(x)$, and let $X\in[0,w]$. Let $B(x)$ be a measurable real-valued and let $k\in[0,w]$ be a known scalar.
Is it true that:
\begin{equation}
E[B(X)|X>k]=\frac{1}{1-F(k)}\int_{k}^{w}B(x)f(x)dx
\end{equation}

Thanks.

Comment: by "distribution $f(x)$" you mean "density $f(x)$", correct?

Comment: Also, I assume $F$ is the distribution function of $X$?

Comment: Yes, $f(x)$ is the PDF and $F(x)$ is the CDF of $X$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following equation is by definition $$E[B(x) | \{ X > k \}] = \int_{x = 0}^{\omega} B(x) f_{X|\{X > k \}}(x) dx$$

where $f_{X | \{X > k \}}(x)$ is the conditional distribution of $X$ conditioned on the event $\{X > k \}$ which is just equal, also by definition, to $\frac{f_X(x)}{P(X > k)} = \frac{f_X(x)}{1 - P(X < k)}$ for $k < x < \omega$.

$$f_{X | \{X > k \}}(x) = \begin{cases}
\frac{f_X(x)}{1 - P(X < k)} & k < x < \omega\\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

Therefore,

$$E[B(x) | \{ X > k \}] = \int_{x = k}^{\omega} B(x) \frac{f_X(x)}{1 - P(X < k)} dx$$

Comment: Thanks. So my definition was essentially correct?

Comment: Yes. I just made some edits to make it more mathematically correct.

Comment: Why you write $x=k$ in the integral?

Comment: In the first integral, it should be $x = 0$ as a lower bound. In the second integral, the conditional distribution is $0$ for $0 < x < k$ so the lower bound becomes $x = k$.