# Am I computing this conditional expectation correctly?

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation

Let $f_X(t) = (5/6 - t^2)\mathsf 1_{(-1,1)}(t)$ be the density of $X$. Then according to [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3482873/conditional-expectation-and-lotus-to-prove-an-identity-for-mathbb-ebx-mid-x#3482892), we may compute
$$
\mathbb E[X\mid X>k] = \frac1{1-F(k)}\int_k^1 tf_X(t)\ \mathsf dt
$$
We have $1-F(k) = \int_k^1 (5/6 - t^2)\ \mathsf dt = \frac{1}{6} \left(2 k^3-5 k+3\right)$
and
$$
\int_k^1 t(5/6-t^2)\ \mathsf dt = \frac{1}{12} \left(3 k^4-5 k^2+2\right),
$$
hence
$$
\mathbb E[X\mid X>k] = \frac{\frac{1}{12} \left(3 k^4-5 k^2+2\right)}{\frac{1}{6} \left(2 k^3-5 k+3\right)},
$$
so that
$$
\mathbb E[X\mid X>k] = \frac{1}{2} \left(2 k^3-5 k+3\right) \left(3 k^4-5 k^2+2\right).
$$

Comment: In the second approach you are using something like Bayes rule which is only true for the probabilities and not the expectations.

Comment: The second approach is something I saw posted on another question here and wasn't sure about. So it is good to indeed learn that it is wrong.

Comment: It is $tf_X(t)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no $\omega$ in your question.. but there is one in the other post, you formula should be :

$$E[X\mid X>k] = \frac1{1-F(k)}\int_k^\infty tf_X(t)\ \mathsf dt$$

Let $-1 \leq k \leq 1$ (the other cases are trivial)

$$F(k)=P(X<k)=\int_{-\infty}^k f_X(t)\ \mathsf dt=\frac{5}{6}(k+1)-\left[\frac{k^3}{3}+\frac{1}{3}\right]$$

$$E\left[X 1_{X>k}\right]=\int_{-\infty}^\infty tf_X(t)1_{t>k}\ \mathsf dt=\int_{k}^1 {t\left(\frac{5}{6}-t^2\right)}\ \mathsf dt=\frac{5}{6}\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{k^2}{2}\right)-\left[\frac{1}{4}-\frac{k^4}{4}\right]$$

You can finish by using the following formula
$$E\left[X |X>k\right]=\frac{E\left[X 1_{X>k}\right]}{P(X>k)}$$

Comment: Oh, I was using $w$ as the upper bound for integration instead of $1$ for some reason. Let me fix that.

Comment: Why do you compute $\mathbb E[X\mathsf 1_{\{X>k\}}]$ in your post when it is not used in this method of computing the conditional expectation?

Comment: Now I am getting the conditional expectation to be identically $1$, which clearly can't be right. What am I missing?

Comment: you forgot the $t$ in your formula. You delete the second formula, it was correct

Comment: Right, because I am integrating the map $t\to t$, of course there needs to be a factor of $t$ in the integrand. Thank you.